# Why does PHP post increment not behave as expected when in an array [ ] operation?

Tags: php

My Question is why does the post increment not function on the first element but then works as expected when it is contained within an array [ ] element ?

Here is a snippet of what I was doing that behaves unexpectedly:

When I use this code ...

```
$lessonIndex = 0;
$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Title'] = 'Lesson 1';
$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Start'] = $TimeArray[$EventArray[$lessonIndex++]['Title']]['Start'];

$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Title'] = 'Lesson 2';
$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Start'] = $TimeArray[$EventArray[$lessonIndex++]['Title']]['Start'];

$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Title'] = 'Lesson 3';
$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Start'] = $TimeArray[$EventArray[$lessonIndex++]['Title']]['Start'];
```

The $EventArray[$lessonIndex] contents will be skip index 0 then index 1 will get what was destined for index 0 and the increment proceeds as expected through the rest of the code, but with the results being off by one.

If I do this instead:

```
$lessonIndex = 0;
$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Title'] = 'Lesson 1';
$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Start'] = $TimeArray[$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Title']]['Start'];
$lessonIndex++;

$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Title'] = 'Lesson 2';
$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Start'] = $TimeArray[$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Title']]['Start'];
$lessonIndex++;

$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Title'] = 'Lesson 3';
$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Start'] = $TimeArray[$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Title']]['Start'];
$lessonIndex++;
```

Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You should not use a variable that gets incremented more than once in a line, else you risk this kind of unexpected behaviour.

```
$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Start'] = $TimeArray[$EventArray[$lessonIndex++]['Title']]['Start'];
```

What happens is that

1. First the rvalue (The value right of the equals sign `=`) gets
   evaluated.
2. After that evaluation, `$lessonIndex` will get incremented.
3. Only then will the lvalue be fetched, but by that time `$lessonIndex`
   has already been incremented.

So this would be equal to writing

```
$lessonIndex = 0;
$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Title'] = 'Lesson 1';
$somevalue = $TimeArray[$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Title']]['Start'];
$lessonIndex++;
$EventArray[$lessonIndex]['Start'] = $somevalue;
```

Comment: Thanks,That is the part I was missing.  I was thinking left to right.  Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the `++` operator incremented the value, then sent the result as the array index.

In your second example, the value was sent as the array index, *then* incremented.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has order of operations. The `++` is evaluated BEFORE PHP calculates what array index you're referring to. So you increment the value, THEN that new value is returned and used as the array index.

```
$a = 0;
$x = $arr[$a++];
```

is functionally identical to

```
$a = 0;
$a++;
$x = $arr[$a]; // aka $arr[1];
```

Comment: I actually think that his eventarray[1][start] gets the value from eventarray[0][title] because the rvalue gets evaluated first, causing the increment. [PHP does make a difference between pre-increment and post-increment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).